# how to update all the values of a column in a dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which has a non formated Date column :

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
|CDOPEINT| bbbbbbbbbb|    Date|
+--------+-----------+--------+
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|13190326|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|10190309|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|36190908|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|07190214|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|13190328|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|23190608|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|13190330|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|26190630|
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

the date column is formated as : wwyyMMdd (week, year, month, day) which I want to format to YYYYMMdd, for that a have a method : *format* that do that.
so my question is how could I map all the values of column Date to the needed format? 
 here is the output that I want :

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|CDOPEINT| bbbbbbbbbb|      Date|
+--------+-----------+----------+
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/26|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/09|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/09/08|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/02/14|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/28|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/06/08|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/30|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/06/30|
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spark 2.4.3 using unix_timestamp you can convert data to the expected output.

```
scala> var df2 =spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","13190326"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","10190309"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","36190908"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","07190214"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","13190328"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","23190608"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","13190330"),("AAA","bbbbbbbbbbb","26190630"))).toDF("CDOPEINT","bbbbbbbbbb","Date")

scala> df2.withColumn("Date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substring(col("Date"),3,7),"yyMMdd"),"yyyy/MM/dd")).show
+--------+-----------+----------+
|CDOPEINT| bbbbbbbbbb|      Date|
+--------+-----------+----------+
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/26|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/09|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/09/08|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/02/14|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/28|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/06/08|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/03/30|
|     AAA|bbbbbbbbbbb|2019/06/30|
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

let me know if you have any query related to this.

Comment: IT WORKS LIKE A CHAMR,

Answer (score 0):

If the date involves values from 2000 and the `Date` column in your original dataframe is of Integer type,you could try something like this

```scala
def getDate =(date:Int) =>{
    val dateString = date.toString.drop(2).sliding(2,2)
dateString.zipWithIndex.map{
    case(value,index) => if(index ==0) 20+value else value
}.mkString("/")
}
```

Then create a UDF which calls this function

```scala
val updateDateUdf = udf(getDate)
```

If originalDF is the original Dataframe that you have, you could then change the dataframe like this

```scala
val updatedDF = originalDF.withColumn("Date",updateDateUdf(col("Date")))
```